# recently instld ubuntu on laptop having both ssd(240gb) and hdd(1tb)hdd has windows. But whenever I open ubuntu, the drive name changes automatically

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

The hdd on which windows is installed has 4 partitions in total and I can access in ubuntu as well. However when I log on in ubuntu the partition names appear changed in its file explorer.
Edit: I think I wasn't able to put it clearly....
See, whenever I boot into ubuntu, a particular drive name changes everytime in Ubuntu's file explorer say if it was A in previous boot, it'll be B this time and C next time I boot up. Any answers why this is happening?

Comment: What's the question? Are you expecting Ubuntu to use Windows partition names (D:)?

Comment: It's currently not clear what you are asking.  Please edit your question and include more context and details and a clear description of what you are trying to do and a description of what is wrong.  It's best if you would ask a question, as this will make it more clear what you need answered.

Comment: FWIW; Windows and Linux interprets and displays partition info very differently.